# Use Flags Enum as a normal Enum

Tags: c#, enums

Is there a way to optionally force a `[Flags]` enum to be "non-Flags" for specific uses?

For example, say I have

```
enum MyEnum {
     X ,
     Y , 
     Z 
 }
```

Now let's say I have two classes `A` and `B`. Class B will mostly be used within an `IEnumerable<B>`. Class A is responsible for parsing this list, but only when the enum matches a particular value;

```
 class B {
      MyEnum MyProperty { get; set; }
  }

 class A {
      MyEnum Target = MyEnum.C;
      void DoSomething(IEnumerable<B> list) {

           for (var b in list) {
               if (b.MyProperty == this.Target) {
                   // Do Some Work
               }
           }
      }
 }
```

Now suppose I want class A to be able to work with multiple types of B. I could add the [Flags] attribute to my enum and do something like this:

```
[Flags]
enum MyEnum {
     None = 0,
     X = 1,
     Y = 2, 
     Z = 4
 }


 class B {
      MyEnum MyProperty { get; set; }
  }

 class A {
      MyEnum Target = MyEnum.X | MyEnum.Z;
      void DoSomething(IEnumerable<B> list) {

           for (var b in list) {
               if (this.Target.HasFlag(b.MyProperty)) {
                   // Do Some Work
               }
           }
      }
 }
```

However, class B's `MyProperty` can now be used as a flag, which is a problem because there's no such thing as a `MyEnum.X | MyEnum.Y` in the context of `B.MyProperty`. It makes sense within `A` because I am targeting various kinds of class B.

The work around that I've come up with is this:

```
enum MyEnum {
     None = 0,
     X = 1,
     Y = 2, 
     Z = 4
 }

[Flags]
enum MyEnumTarget {
     None = 0,
     X = 1,
     Y = 2, 
     Z = 4
 }

 class B {
      MyEnum MyProperty { get; set; }
  }

 class A {
      MyEnumTarget Target = MyEnumTarget.X | MyEnumTarget.Z;
      void DoSomething(IEnumerable<B> list) {

           for (var b in list) {
               if (this.Target.HasFlag((MyEnumTarget)b.MyProperty)) {
                   // Do Some Work
               }
           }
      }
 }
```

While this works, it's definitely messy. I now have to keep track of two different enums. Any change I make in one, I have to make in the other and I have to make sure that the values are syncronized. On top of that I now have to cast to `MyEnumTarget` to be able to pass the value to `Enum.HasFlag`. Granted I could do bit-wise operations but then its not always so obvious what the intent is. Either way, I'd still need two "matching" enums.

Is there no better way to do to this? Is there some way to use a single enum type and force some sort of [NoFlags] attribute on `B.MyProperty`. Or is having the two enums considered the best way / good practice?

I'm using C#6.0 if that matters

Comment: Bear in mind that, flags enum or not, *any* integer value can be cast into a value of type `MyEnum`. You need to validate the values you're working with either way. Enums are not constrained to only defined values.

Comment: I am aware that any integer can be cast to this. However I'm not worried about someone assigning a value to it. All of this is internal to the assembly and isn't exposed to anyone else. Internally we know how to use it and essentially wouldn't be misusing the properties... its more as a precaution for someone making modifications in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally, each enum type either *is* designed to have be a bit mask, or isn't. Options you might consider:

- Two separate enums, as per your code
- One non-flags enum, but make `A.Property` a `List<MyEnum>` or similar
- One flags enum, but make the `B.Property` setter validate that only a single bit is set, throwing an `ArgumentException` otherwise

Comment: My first Jon Skeet reply!!! I had considered the List approach. As I mention in my comment above, this is all internal to the assembly; the properties aren't going to be exposed to the caller of these classes; they'll only be set by myself and/or my team as we develop our application. Right now during development, we would know to only assign single values. My concern was more for the next guy that joins our team or in a year from now if we forget -- basically a precaution.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33: That sounds like you should validate it on the setter then :) (or use a collection...)

Answer (score 0):

What's different between the two uses? It sounds like these **should** be two different enums because their **meanings** are different. The **contracts** of their use are different. If these were classes, I would suggest applying the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle), because they are used in a different way by different clients.

As these are enums, you can either wrap them in classes with interface segregation, or at least distinguish between the two enums.